# Python/Pandas: Joining a data frame to itself to get previous year’s numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Input data set:** I have a pandas DataFrame, `fin_df`, like this:

| AcctID | Cntry | Year | Revenue | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J8765 | USA | 2009 | 3000 | 600 |
| A5001 | USA | 2015 | 2000 | 700 |
| A5001 | USA | 2011 | 5000 | 300 |
| A5001 | USA | 2014 | 6000 | 400 |
| A5001 | USA | 2012 | 1500 | 200 |
| J8765 | USA | 2008 | 8000 | 1000 |
| A5001 | CAN | 2013 | 7000 | 800 |

The **primary key** is `[AcctID, Cntry, Year]`.  The **unique identifier** for a given customer is `[AcctID, Cntry]`.  (Just because there's an `AcctID = A5001` for both USA & CAN, we can NOT assume they are the same customer.)

The records are NOT sorted.  They can appear in any order.

We want to join this DataFrame to itself on the previously-mentioned keys, in order to **backfill each year's financial records with its respective previous year's values**.  2 additional columns will be appended: `PrevRevenue` & `PrevIncome`.

**The expected output is**

| AcctID | Cntry | Year | Revenue | Income | PrevRevenue | PrevIncome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| J8765 | USA | 2009 | 3000 | 600 | 8000 | 1000 |
| A5001 | USA | 2015 | 2000 | 700 | 6000 | 400 |
| A5001 | USA | 2011 | 5000 | 300 | null | null |
| A5001 | USA | 2014 | 6000 | 400 | null | null |
| A5001 | USA | 2012 | 1500 | 200 | 5000 | 300 |
| J8765 | USA | 2008 | 8000 | 1000 | null | null |
| A5001 | CAN | 2013 | 7000 | 800 | null | null |

- J8765-USA-2009 gets previous values from J8765-USA-2008.
- A5001-USA-2015 gets previous values from A5001-USA-2014.
- A5001-USA-2011 has null previous values because there is no A5001-USA-2010 in the data set.
- A5001-USA-2014 has null previous values because there is no A5001-USA-2013 in the data set.  There is A5001-**CAN**-2013, but as discussed previously, this is assumed to be a different customer.
- A5001-USA-2012 gets previous values from A5001-USA-2011.
- and so on.

I'm a Pandas novice - how do I go about doing this?  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
fin_df_prev = fin_df.copy()
fin_df_prev.Year += 1
fin_df_prev = fin_df_prev.rename(columns={'Revenue': 'PrevRevenue', 'Income':'PrevIncome'})
joined_df = fin_df.merge(fin_df_prev, on=['AcctID', 'Cntry', 'Year'], how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks AliVar!  What if fin_df is a very, very large table with millions of rows - is making a full copy of it computationally expensive?